# Label layer as symbol colors with QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, labeling, symbology, qgis-3

Is it possible to label a layer using same colors as the categorized symbology of that layer?

It is possible using the *Rule-based labeling*, but it can be difficult for a layer with many categories and maybe it can be done using the *Data-defined override*, but I don't know how to get the color used for every category.

Comment: See here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/383628/88814

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using QGIS 3.4.5, you can write `@symbol_color` in the data defined override for coloring the text:

1. Go to Data defined override -> Edit

[image]

2. Write the following:

`@symbol_color`

[image]

3. Use buffer around the text to see the label
4. Output:

[image]

For multi-layer symbol, note that `@symbol_color` returns the color of the last symbol layer (the one on the bottom, be it visible or not)
[image: ex of multi-layr symbol]

Answer (score 0):

I can report that this feature does not work if the labeled layer uses geometry generators – the color reverts to black. Seems to be a bug. [image: symbol color reverts to black on layer with geometry generator]

[There is a workaround for this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314706/label-layer-as-symbol-colors-with-qgis-3#comment589225_360135) (put a standard symbol in, disable visibility, move it to the bottom of the symbology list - @symbol_color will always pick up the colour of the bottom-most symbol.)

Comment: If you discover a bug, please report it directly on https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues

Comment: Please raise this as a separate issue or comment. Your answer will likely be deleted but i have a workaround for this (put a standard symbol in, disable visibility, move it to the bottom of the symbology list - `@symbol_color` will always pick up the colour of the bottom-most symbol.)

Comment: Nice trick @she_weeds, i confirm your workaround does the job ...

Comment: @she_weeds, thank you for the trick, it saves my day.