# Match label color to polygon color

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression, qgsexpression

I have a polygon layer in which I'm labelling each polygon on the map. I am trying to figure out how to make the label colour match that of the underlying polygon (with a white buffer around the label so as to make it readable against the layer below). Currently all text is black:
[image]

I know I can enter a QGIS expression that probably works, but not sure what it is! Here's how I can get to the Edit... expression dialog:
[image]

The list of Color expression options doesn't show anything obvious:
[image]

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: @symbol_color should do

Comment: Have you checked the answer to the [Label layer as symbol colors with QGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/314709/63384)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@symbol_color is the answer!

Thanks to @mrxsquared